# How to set required fields in PATCH API in Swagger UI

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

I'm using **drf-spectacular** and here's code in `settings.py`

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'TITLE': 'TITLE',
    'VERSION': '1.0.0',
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM': True,
    'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ["custom.url_remover.preprocessing_filter_spec"],  
}
```

in `serializers.py`

```
class ChangePasswordSerilaizer(serializers.Serializer):
    current_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, min_length=8, required=True)
    new_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, min_length=8, required=True)
    confirm_new_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, min_length=8, required=True)
```

but still fields in request body are showing not required

[image]

Comment: can you also put the view function here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS`

```
    SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
        'TITLE': 'APP NAME',
        'VERSION': '1.0.0',
        'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM': True,
        'PREPROCESSING_HOOKS': ["custom.url_remover.preprocessing_filter_spec"], 
        'COMPONENT_SPLIT_PATCH': False, 
    }
```

by default `COMPONENT_SPLIT_PATCH` is `true` in `SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS` so you can simply override(`'COMPONENT_SPLIT_PATCH': False`) it to fix this problem